# NODEJS dyanamic image editing with gm

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I am using [gm](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/) for node js in windows.

I already installed ghostscript, graphisMagick and ImageMagick.

I want to blur an image and put text on that.

```
gm(dir + '/original.png')
  .blur(8, 4)
  .drawText(-20, 98, "graphics magick")
  .write(dir + '/drawing.png', function(err){
    if (err) return console.dir(arguments)
    console.log(this.outname + ' created  :: ' + arguments[3])
  }
)
```

The draw text is failing with following console output.

```
{ '0':
   { [Error: Command failed: gm convert: Unable to read font (n019003l.pfb) [No
such file or directory].
   ] code: 1, signal: null },
  '1': '',
  '2': 'gm convert: Unable to read font (n019003l.pfb) [No such file or director
y].\r\n',
  '3': 'gm "convert" "C:\\Work\\Rnd\\bkop_final\\example/imgs/original.png" "-st
roke" "#ffffff" "-draw" "circle 10,10 20,10" "-pointsize" "12" "-font" "Helvetic
a.ttf" "-draw" "text 30,20 \\"GMagick!\\"" "C:\\Work\\Rnd\\bkop_final\\example/i
mgs/drawing.png"' }
```

if i remove the drawText works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is missing a font. It has nothing to do with node.js.
It is about the ghostscript installation.

Are you sure ghostscript is in your PATH and
did you read

http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Install.htm (see "Fonts")

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install ghostscript
```

did it for me on the mac. MacOS Sierra to be precise.